# How to edit individual fields in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to update fields of my models by showing the values and then having a little "edit" button next to it, which would turn the label into textbox/dropdownlist and the edit button should disappear and instead show a Save and Cancel buttons. The save and cancel buttons should disappear when you click on them or on any other thing in the page (and the edit button should come back) .

I'm pretty sure that this will require some javascript (hopefully it could be done all in jQuery).

Do you have any suggestions (links/tutorials) on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article might help you out http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Also, just Google "jquery edit in place" and there should be a lot of articles to help you out.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know it was called like that.